# Joining Excel file with shapefile

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, excel

I am using QGIS version 2.18.19. I have created a shapefile using a script and its attribute table is empty as shown in below image.

[image]

I am adding an Excel file. It includes a table as the input to the script appeared as follows:

[image]

I want to join this table in to my above mention shapefile. I want my shapefile attribute table to be visible as shown below after joining Excel table in to my shapefile.

[image]

[image]

How can I do this using QGIS?

Comment: A "join" is a table operation to zipper rows from two tables together. If source table has no rows, the join has no rows.

Comment: Will your metadata file always have exactly the same format / layout?

Comment: Yes.My metadata file always have exactly the same format.

Comment: I have managed to find a solution for this question.Thank you all for your valuable comments

Comment: Could you please post the answer / solution you found (answer your own question)? That way other people can benefit!

Comment: I am not allowed to paste my answer.it gives a error massage.it says my answer is  too long.